# Windows 7, is there a way to verify it's checking for updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows

A fresh install of Windows 7 HomePremium 64-bit. I know the checking for updates service takes hours, sometimes a full day or more to run. But I don't see it anywhere in my task manager process list, so is there a way I can actually check if it's downloading data from Microsoft or if it's just a visual glitch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Windows Update (`Start > All Programs > Windows Update`) to see what it is doing. If it is downloading or installing updates there will be an progress indicator. If there isn't, you can manually start it by clicking <kbd>Check for Updates</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, there is a progress indicator. I was just confused because I expected there to be something in the task manager's process list.